# Windows Event Viewer -> XML -> Custom View

Tags: xml, windows-server-2012, event-viewer

I have the below query - I want it to report on only user1 & user2 based on ObjectName or RelativeTargetName

But it reports on all users based on the objectName or RelativeTargetName

How can I control this?

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='SubjectUserName'] and (Data='user1'  or Data='user2')]]
   and
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='ObjectName'] and (Data='E:\Path\To\Folder')]]
   or
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='RelativeTargetName'] and (Data='Path\To\Folder')]]
  </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked

```
<QueryList>
  <Query Id="0" Path="Security">
    <Select Path="Security">
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='ObjectName'] and (Data='E:\Path\To\Folder')]] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='SubjectUserName'] and (Data='user1'  or Data='user2')]]
   or
   *[EventData[Data[@Name='RelativeTargetName'] and (Data='Path\To\Folder')]] and *[EventData[Data[@Name='SubjectUserName'] and (Data='user1' or Data='user2')]]
  </Select>
  </Query>
</QueryList>
```